# Add semi-transparent overlay on imageview

Tags: android, imageview, transparency

How can I add semi-transparent overlay on imageview?

[image]

change it to

[image]

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Set your imageview like this::

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageview"
android:layout_width="wrap_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_parent"
android:foreground="@drawable/image_overlay"
android:src="@drawable/your_image" />
```

image_overlay.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#401C87C0"
        android:centerColor="#401C87C0"
        android:endColor="#401C87C0"
        />
</shape>
```

I use color-code = #1C87C0 and set it to 25% opacity so the final color-code be like #401C87C0. You can change color opacity changing the first 2 characters in the color definition according to your requirement ::

```
100% — FF
99% — FC
98% — FA
97% — F7
96% — F5
95% — F2
94% — F0
93% — ED
92% — EB
91% — E8

90% — E6
89% — E3
88% — E0
87% — DE
86% — DB
85% — D9
84% — D6
83% — D4
82% — D1
81% — CF

80% — CC
79% — C9
78% — C7
77% — C4
76% — C2
75% — BF
74% — BD
73% — BA
72% — B8
71% — B5

70% — B3
69% — B0
68% — AD
67% — AB
66% — A8
65% — A6
64% — A3
63% — A1
62% — 9E
61% — 9C

60% — 99
59% — 96
58% — 94
57% — 91
56% — 8F
55% — 8C
54% — 8A
53% — 87
52% — 85
51% — 82

50% — 80
49% — 7D
48% — 7A
47% — 78
46% — 75
45% — 73
44% — 70
43% — 6E
42% — 6B
41% — 69

40% — 66
39% — 63
38% — 61
37% — 5E
36% — 5C
35% — 59
34% — 57
33% — 54
32% — 52
31% — 4F

30% — 4D
29% — 4A
28% — 47
27% — 45
26% — 42
25% — 40
24% — 3D
23% — 3B
22% — 38
21% — 36

20% — 33
19% — 30
18% — 2E
17% — 2B
16% — 29
15% — 26
14% — 24
13% — 21
12% — 1F
11% — 1C

10% — 1A
9% — 17
8% — 14
7% — 12
6% — 0F
5% — 0D
4% — 0A
3% — 08
2% — 05
1% — 03
0% — 00
```

Comment: glad this helps you.

Comment: Attribute android:foreground has no effect on API levels lower than 23

Comment: Gradient with all colors the same doesn't make sense. You can just set `<solid android:color="#401C87C0" />` instead

Answer (score 12):

You can surround your ImageView within a FrameLayout.

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:foreground="@color/semi_transparent_color">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:src="@drawable/your_image" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

You can use a semi-transparent color here, maybe something like #22000000.

Comment: this is better answer, because Attribute android:foreground has no effect on API levels lower than 23 we have to wrap it inside a frame layout

Answer (score 6):

Just add an alpha like this `android:alpha="0.6"` in your `ImageView` and assign a base color in your `FrameLayout` like `blue=#2196F3`.

```
<FrameLayout
     android:background="#2196F3"
     android:layout_width="..."
     android:layout_height="...">

     <ImageView
         android:alpha="0.6"
         android:layout_width="..."
         android:layout_height="..."
         android:src="@drawable/image" />

</FrameLayout>
```

The alpha value is ranging from `1.0` until `0.0`. As an example :

- 1.0 Is not-transparent
- 0.5 Is semi-transparent
- 0.0 fully-transparent

Answer (score 4):

A simpler solution could be to use a ColorFilter on the ImageView with PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER

```
ImageView.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(
        context,
        R.color.black_opacity_200),
        PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER
);
```

If you want to get rid of the overlay simply clear it

```
ImageView.clearColorFilter()
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to **add transparent overlay above the Imageview** you can use this :

```
imageView.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_black_view), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER);
```

**No need to add any extra views over view or no need to add any alpha.**

Answer (score 3):

for me, the selected answer didn't worked.But I got it using [layer-list.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList).All you got to do is to create a filter file(having your topmost color), a layer-drawable file(joining your filtercolor and image) and use this layer-drawable in your image view.
filter.xml

```
<shape
    android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <gradient
        android:startColor="#cf64b5f6"
        android:endColor="#cf1E88E5"
        android:angle="270"
        />

</shape>
```

- layerlist_drawable.xml

  ```
  <layer-list
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/my_img" />
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/filter" />
  </layer-list>
  ```
- main_activity.xml :

  ```
  <ImageView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="180dp"
      android:scaleType="centerCrop"
      android:src="@drawable/layerlist_drawable"
      />
  ```

[image]

Comment: Really useful when not working with an imageview directly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add a simple View as the last child in your FrameLayout and set its background to a semi-transparent color. Set the visibility of the overlay View appropriately (`View.VISIBLE` or `View.GONE`).